# "Вонь" и "внимать"

Tags: этимология

Являются ли слова "вонь" и "внимать" этимологически однокоренными?

Answer (score 0):

Вонь, благовоние и обоняние имеют общий корень, в котором есть звук "в".

В основе слов внимать, понимать, обнимать совсем другой корень, и по смыслу и по звучанию. Звука "в" в нем точно нет.

Мне не удалось найти что либо общее в словах "вонь" и "внимать".

Comment: @ guaranteen, а где в слове обоняние звук в?

Comment: В слове обоняние звука "в" нет, а в его "этимологическом" корне он есть.  Подобно словам обоз, обещание и пр.

Comment: Но так надо написать "этимологически".